# SQLSTATE[42000] Error on aggregation functions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

Hello I am getting a error in my SQL Query and can't figure it out what is wrong. Here is the query so far with the help of Barmar.

```
 $query = "SELECT c.*, count(s.curso_id) as count, SUM(IF(s.status = 'aprobado', 1, 0)) AS count_approved , SUM(IF(s.status = 'cupolleno', 1, 0)) AS count_cupolleno
    , SUM(IF(s.status = 'cancelado', 1, 0)) AS count_cancelado, SUM(IF(s.status = 'noacion', 1, 0)) AS count_noacion, SUM(IF(s.status = 'ama_de_casa', 1, 0)) AS count_ama_de_casa
    , SUM(IF(s.status = 'cliente_externo', 1, 0)) AS count_cliente_externo
    FROM cursos_modulos AS c
    LEFT JOIN subscriptions AS s ON s.curso_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.userID = s.user_id GROUP BY c.id WHERE 1";
                if (!empty($id)) { $query .= " AND c.id = '$id'"; }
                if (!empty($ciudad)) { $query .= " AND c.ciudad = '$ciudad'"; }
                if (!empty($tipo)) { $query .= " AND c.tipo = '$tipo'"; }
                if (!empty($titulo))  { $query .=" AND c.titulo = '$titulo'"; }
                if (!empty($status))  { $query .= " AND c.status = '$status'"; }
 $paginate = new pagination($page, $query, $options);
```

the Error Message which I am getting is the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 1 AND
>   c.id = '1' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 6' in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\admin\class\pagination.php:376 Stack trace: #0
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\admin\class\pagination.php(376):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\admin\class\pagination.php(202):
>   pagination->excecute_query() #2
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\admin\class\pagination.php(162):
>   pagination->run(1, 'SELECT c.*, cou...', Array) #3
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\admin\search.php(146):
>   pagination->__construct(1, 'SELECT c.*, cou...', Array) #4 {main}
>   thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\admin\class\pagination.php on line
>   376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group by` clause should come after the `where` clause. I.e.:

```
$query = "SELECT c.*, count(s.curso_id) as count, SUM(IF(s.status = 'aprobado', 1, 0)) AS count_approved , SUM(IF(s.status = 'cupolleno', 1, 0)) AS count_cupolleno
, SUM(IF(s.status = 'cancelado', 1, 0)) AS count_cancelado, SUM(IF(s.status = 'noacion', 1, 0)) AS count_noacion, SUM(IF(s.status = 'ama_de_casa', 1, 0)) AS count_ama_de_casa
, SUM(IF(s.status = 'cliente_externo', 1, 0)) AS count_cliente_externo
FROM cursos_modulos AS c
LEFT JOIN subscriptions AS s ON s.curso_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.userID = s.user_id WHERE 1";
            if (!empty($id)) { $query .= " AND c.id = '$id'"; }
            if (!empty($ciudad)) { $query .= " AND c.ciudad = '$ciudad'"; }
            if (!empty($tipo)) { $query .= " AND c.tipo = '$tipo'"; }
            if (!empty($titulo))  { $query .=" AND c.titulo = '$titulo'"; }
            if (!empty($status))  { $query .= " AND c.status = '$status'"; } 
$query .= " GROUP BY c.id";
```

Comment: This looks like the right solution the only problem is that it gives me an error; Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$paginate' (T_VARIABLE) in E:\xampp\htdocs\admin\search.php on line 147

Comment: I was missing a `;` at the end of the last statement. Adding it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

what does `where 1` do for you? Try killing that.

the following does not throw a 1064 error:

```
create table cursos_modulos
(   id int not null

);

create table subscriptions
(   curso_id int not null,
    user_id int not null,
    status varchar(100) not null
);

create table users
(   userID int not null
);

SELECT c.id,
count(s.curso_id) as count, 
SUM(IF(s.status = 'aprobado', 1, 0)) AS count_approved, 
SUM(IF(s.status = 'cupolleno', 1, 0)) AS count_cupolleno, 
SUM(IF(s.status = 'cancelado', 1, 0)) AS count_cancelado, 
SUM(IF(s.status = 'noacion', 1, 0)) AS count_noacion, 
SUM(IF(s.status = 'ama_de_casa', 1, 0)) AS count_ama_de_casa,
SUM(IF(s.status = 'cliente_externo', 1, 0)) AS count_cliente_externo
FROM cursos_modulos AS c
LEFT JOIN subscriptions AS s ON s.curso_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.userID = s.user_id 
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: it makes the if conditions to be considered in the query at the end.

Comment: 1 is `true` in mysql. `where 1` is a completely legal (albeit somewhat useless) mysql syntax.

Comment: i changed it mainly to `c.id` based on your group by.Iif you have `c.*` with that group by, good luck, it will probably deliver bad answers, or generally will. Table.* should be avoided at all costs, unless it is pretty close to throw-away code.